# Is there a way to deploy an iOS app with Core Data database already prepopulated?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to publish an app that would have my Core Data database already prepopulated with data.  I don't want at first launch to programmatically populate the data from a file in the resource bundle because that would duplicate the amount of disk usage on the user's device.  For example, if my data is 250Mb stored in a resource bundle file, and I use that file to populate the database at first launch time, the original resource bundle file remains, and the database now also holds that data, resulting in redundant disk usage of 250Mb.

I've seen many tutorials showing how to "preload" data at first launch.  That is not a solution to this question.

Comment: The Apple documentation on this subject is a little old but it still exists and is relevant. There are also a few blogs in the subject. One seemingly reasonable method (that I’ve not yet tried) is to add two persistent stores to one coordinator, the seed store read only and the permanent store read write. Add to a single context, save, then all data is persisted to the permanent read write store. Then finally delete the seed store from the bundle.

Comment: You can't delete the seed store from the bundle, the bundle is read-only.  @andrewz, You can't Really avoid having a copy of your data in the bundle and a copy on disk if you want to ship the data with the app.  You could transfer the initial data from a network location on first launch

Answer (score 1):

You say: *I don't want at first launch to programmatically populate the data from a file in the resource bundle because that would duplicate the amount of disk usage on the user's device.*

Have you considered using compressed database files?

I have published quite large Cora Data databases with my former app [Taxame](https://appadvice.com/app/taxame/925717857). See [databases files](https://gitlab.com/ms152718212/taxonomicdatabase/-/tree/master/result). I've stored them as compressed files (zip) in the resource bundle. 425MB SQLite DB compressed was only 96MB.

During the first launch of the app on the fly the smallest database has been unzipped. The other databases optionally could be loaded by the user.

On iPadPro 2 (A10X):

[image]

Info: "ITIS" database is 140MB (compressed 67MB) "ITIS An" database is 425MB (compressed 96MB).

I've used [Objective-Zip](https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip).

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable alternative.